# error in qml type converting while qml styling

Tags: qt, qml

first , I found two post and want to try their skinnable idea as follows :

- [Dynamically change QML theme at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36335481/dynamically-change-qml-theme-at-runtime/36399339#36399339)
- [Qt 5 Styling: dynamically load qml files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23518071/qt-5-styling-dynamically-load-qml-files/25866188#25866188)

I almost copied their code , but failed and errors occurs:

```
while code running , it reports error showing "Unable to assign AbstractStyle_QMLTYPE_37 to AbstractStyle_QMLTYPE_0".
```

here is my code:

```
// AbstractStyle.qml
import QtQuick 2.0
QtObject {
 property int textSize;
 property color textColor;
}

// StyleA.qml
import QtQuick 2.0
AbstractStyle {
 textSize : 20
 textColor : "red"
}

// StyleB.qml
import QtQuick 2.0
AbstractStyle {
 textSize : 50
 textColor : "green"
}

//componentCreation.js
var component;
var sprite;
function createStyleObject(item, stylePath)
{
 component = Qt.createComponent(stylePath);
 if( component.status == Component.Ready ){
  sprite = component.createObject(item);
  console.log("[!!!OK!!!]componentCreation.js:" + stylePath + " component ready");
}
else
 console.log("componentCreation.js:" + stylePath + " component not ready");
if (sprite === null)
 console.log("componentCreation.js: error creating " + stylePath + " object");
else
 return sprite;
}

//main.cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

 QQuickView *view = new QQuickView;
 view->setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);
 view->setSource(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///main.qml")));
 view->show();

 return app.exec();
}

//main.qml
import "qrc:/styles/componentCreation.js" as Style
Item {
 id : base
 ...
 property AbstractStyle currentStyle : Style.createStyleObject(base, "qrc:/StyleA.qml");

 Text {
  x: 100
  y: 0
  font.pixelSize: currentStyle.textSize
  color: currentStyle.textColor
  text: "Hello World"
 }
 ...
}
```

Plus : The development environment is vs2015 in windows and qtcreator in Ubuntu , both used Qt 5.10.1

Comment: With Qt 5.12.1 on Linux I do not observe that problem

Comment: Try changing your `property AbstractStyle currentStyle : ...` line to `property var currentStyle : ...`.

Answer (score 0):

@eyllanesc @TrebuchetMS tks to both of you

well , after some tests , it comes to conclusion:

this works in Qt 5.12.0 and above

```
property AbstractStyle currentStyle : Style.createStyleObject(base, "qrc:/StyleA.qml");
```

these two works in Qt 5.10.1 and above

```
property QtObject currentStyle : Style.createStyleObject(base, "qrc:/StyleA.qml");
property var currentStyle : Style.createStyleObject(base, "qrc:/StyleA.qml");
```

Comment: It seems that Qt 5.12 has improved in the recognition of data types. :-)